programming Raspbery pi model B remotely
recently I have acquired raspberry 1 model B for a very cheap price. I want to learn some python on it but Desktop version is super laggy and command line isn't very practical for code writing. I know that it is possible to program pi4 via SSH.
Is it possible to do this or any other similar way using raspberry pi 1? What is the best way to do some coding using these old boards?
UPDATE:
So after trying out the example I added I get this error:

That is the reason why I am searching for any other method (if there is one for raspberry pi 1)

Why not learn Python on the machine you plan to use to SSH to the Pi?

I'm planing to use raspberry with esp32 or other mcus and write code in C

The only language mentioned in your question is Python.

If you are intending to use the Pi to flash code to an ESP that you write on a Windows box, it would have made more sense to just ask about that in the first place :\  As per other stack exchange sites, we are not discussion oriented whereby you casually introduce some broad context and then casually narrow it down with edits and comments.  Please take the tour to understand better how the site works.

What OS is installed (detail including version)? Which Pi; there never was a Pi1; early models have limited memory.

As a "lightweight" solution, you might consider using Python's built-in IDE - it's called idle; for more info see this. You can use idle over X if you have (or willing to install) an X server on your Windows/Mac machine (native on most Linux). And you can run an X session over SSH by adding the -X option to your SSH cmd.

"What is the best way to do some coding using these old boards?"
I write almost all of my code in an editor on Mac, ftp to the Pi and run via ssh.
The command line editors on Pi are somewhat limited.
For Python Thonny is the recommended IDE and quite usable via VNC if you don't want to use a Pi screen, although I doubt that there is enough RAM on Pi model B to be usable. It does work on a PiB+ running Stretch, but is very sluggish.


Is it possible to do this or any other similar way using raspberry pi 1?

Yes, the OS is the same in all cases (I think there is a recommendation to use the "legacy" version with older models but this is still essentially the same), and SSH is SSH; you simply need to ensure the sshd server is running on the Pi side.

Can you give some tutorials or examples?

I didn't read the whole article you linked and am not a VS Code user, but if it is all ssh based on the Pi side it should hold.  WRT python and such, that's the same story: 1) The OS is the OS is the OS, and this is all about software (except WRT the fact the 1B has a 28-pin break out and most later models have a 40-pin one, something important to be aware of), 2) Python is python is python, so...

...There's no need for special tutorials of the sort whereby we have "How to learn python on a cherry red Dell laptop", "How to learn python on a sky blue Dell laptop", "How to learn python on a mint green Acer laptop" etc. etc.  Might there be little issues with, eg., which gpio library to use, sure, but these are things you will have to discover as you go along.
